# How to search just the Card Title in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Is there a way to search for cards ONLY within their TITLE?

I often am searching for something  like "where is that card on "new website")
If I search on "website" I get 100 cards. If I could narrow that to just the Titles it would help a LOT.

Answer (score 2):

You could try prefixing your search with "name:". For example:

> name:website

This should only return the cards that have your search query in the name, not the contents.